# Matrix derivative (chain rule application)

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Let $x$, $y$ by vectors s.t. $x=f(y)$ and let $B$ be a constant matrix.

What is $\frac{\partial x'Bx}{\partial y}$?

The partial derivative $\frac{\partial x'Bx}{\partial x}=2Bx$ and we need to use the chain rule using the matrix $J=\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}$ but I'm not sure how.

Is it simply $2(Bx)^T J$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General case: Let $\alpha=z^TBx$, then: $$\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=x^TB^T\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+z^TB\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}$$

In your case, $B$ is symmetric, and $z=x$, hence:
$$\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}=x^TB\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}+x^TB\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=2(Bx)^T \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$The
scenario is the following:

You successfully calculated the gradient of a certain function
$$\phi = x^TBx \quad\implies\quad g = \p{\phi}{x} \doteq 2Bx$$
Sometime later you discover that $x$ is not an independent vector,
but is actually dependent on a more fundamental vector for which
you know the Jacobian, i.e.
$$x = f(y) \quad\implies\quad J=\p{x}{y}$$
How do you use this new information to calculate the gradient of the original function?

---

Instead of the ***Chain Rule***,
you can substitute the differentials of the various quantities
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= g^Tdx \quad\qquad dx = J\,dy
}$$
to effect a ***Change of Variables*** from $x\to y\;$ like so
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= g^Tdx \\&= g^T(J\,dy) \\
  &= (J^Tg)^Tdy \\
  &= (2J^TBx)^Tdy \\
\p{\phi}{y} &= 2J^TBx \\
}$$